# Prove the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n}^{\infty} \frac {{x}^{n}}{{(1+2x)}^{n}}$ by finding the small tail

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Prove the uniform convergence of $\sum_{n}^{\infty} \frac {{x}^{n}}{{(1+2x)}^{n}},x\in[1,\infty )$

Can we prove this by using the definition directly:
For every $\epsilon$ there exist N for every $n\geq N$ and $x$,
$\sum_{n+1}^{\infty}\frac {{x}^{n}}{{(1+2x)}^{n}}<\epsilon $

I know how to use Weistrass M-test but still can we find such $N$ as a function of $\epsilon$ to make this inequality true?

Comment: No, since $x^n/(1+2\,x^n) \to 1/2$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: The series does not even converge for any fixed $x \in [1,\infty)$.

Comment: Brackets were lost, now added

Comment: $(x/(1+2x))\leq 1/2$ for all $x\in[1,\infty)$

Comment: I know how to use M-test but how about using the definition directly?

Comment: Use the closed form of the geometric series.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(1+2x)^n}=\frac{x}{1+x}\frac{x^N}{(1+2x)^N}\leqslant\frac{x^N}{(1+2x)^N}<\frac1{2^N}$$